# Bijection logarithm

Tags: group-theory

I have a question regarding showing that something is bijective

Consider the mapping

G is a cyclic group of infinite order

$f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(a^{k})=k$.

This might seem silly, but how does one show formally that this function is bijective?

My other mapping is

G is a cyclic group of finite order

$g:G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_{n}}$ given by $g(b^{i})=[i]$ how would I go on about showing this is bijective formally?

Would you need to use the log rules to show it or what exactly is asked? I have found the mapping and function reversed here it seems more clearly, but I havent been able to figure out the following mapping and function on my own

Comment: You'll need to tell us what $G$ is.

Comment: G is a cyclic group

Comment: $g$ cannot be a bijection, since $G$ is infinite and $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is not.

Comment: sorry should have been finite for the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the infinite case:

1. Surjectivity: You must show that for all $k$, there exists a $g\in G$ for which $f(g) = k$. Let $g=a^k$.
2. Injectivity: You must show that $\ker f=\{1_G\}$. If $f(g)=0$, then writing $g = a^k$ (possible by definition of a cyclic group), you have $f(a^k)=0$, implying $k=0$ (by definition of $f$), so $g=a^0=1_G$.

Notice that these proofs are pretty trivial; they did not use the fact that $G$ was *infinite* cyclic. The interesting part is showing that the map $a^k\mapsto k$ is well-defined in the first place; how do you know some $g\in G$ cannot be written in two ways as $g=a^s$ and $g=a^t$, for $s\neq t$? If that did happen, it would be unclear whether $f(g)=s$ or $f(g)=t$. To prove this cannot happen, you must use the fact $G$ is infinite.

Comment: Yes, $a^s=a^t \iff a^{s-t}=1$. In an infinite cyclic group, $a^k=1$ implies $k=0$. If this were not true, that is if $a^k=1$ for some $k\neq 0$, then $G$ would be finite, since you could show every element of $G$ was equal to $a^r$ for some $r\in\{0,1,\dots,k-1\}$.

Comment: Thank you I think I get it now. The ''surjectiveness'' is pretty clear when you write $g=a^{k}$ so it must be surjective because for all k there exists a g since G is cyclic?... And for the ''injectiveness'' do you use the fact that if $f:G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is a homomorphism then K=<eg> iff f is injective?

Comment: @Djhoe That’s right.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that a function $f$ is bijective, you have to prove:

1. that $f$ is injective. (Let $a$ and $b$ be two elements of the domain, and suppose that $f(a) = f(b)$. Prove that $a = b$.)
2. that $f$ is surjective. (Let $y$ be an element of the codomain. Prove that there exists some element $x$ of the domain such that $f(x) = y$.)

It's usually best to prove these as two separate steps.

Comment: I am well aware that you have show these, and I am well aware of the definitions...

Comment: Then I don't know what you're asking, I'm afraid. You asked "how does one show formally that this function is bijective?", and the answer is: by running it through the definition I gave above. Perhaps you'd like to tell us exactly what you know and what you've tried and where you've got stuck, instead of leaving us to guess...

Comment: I have been trying to use the logarithm rules to show it is injective for the  first one

Comment: do you mind showing me how to do it for just one of them?